# I merged a commit into master and am now getting a message about cherry-picking. Would appreciate advise on what is safe to do

Tags: git, github

Here's the status of my GitHub files:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently cherry-picking commit 41a0584.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Ja/Ja.sln
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

I realize it's suggesting what I should do but could someone explain what it's saying and how I can find out what I might lose if I run the abort option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git doesn't *suggest* you to cherry-pick, it's telling you that **a cherry-pick is currently in process and unfinished**.

Basically, to exit this state and return to normal, you could either abort it or conclude it with a commit :

```
# to get back to the state before cherry-picking
git cherry-pick --abort
```

**`--abort` will bring your branch back to the point where it was just before the cherry-picking started.**

Or, if you *do* want to keep these recent changes brought by said commit `41a0584`

```
# check that you don't have remaining conflicts
git status

# here, resolve any potential conflicts and check if everything is fine

# when you're happy with the current state, as git hints in the output
git cherry-pick --continue
```